# Update or Insert (multiple rows and columns) from subquery in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm trying to do something like this in postgres:

- `UPDATE table1 SET (col1, col2) = (SELECT col2, col3 FROM othertable WHERE othertable.col1 = 123);`
- `INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (SELECT col1, col2 FROM othertable)`

But point 1 is not possible even with postgres 9.0 as mentioned in the docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-update.html)

Also point 2 seems not working. i'm getting the following error: subquery must return only one column.

Hope somebody has a workaround for me. otherwise the queries will take a looot of time :(.

FYI: I'm trying to select different columns from several tables and store them into a temporary table, so that another application can easily fetch the prepared data.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

### For the UPDATE

Use:

```
UPDATE table1 
   SET col1 = othertable.col2,
       col2 = othertable.col3 
  FROM othertable 
 WHERE othertable.col1 = 123;
```

### For the INSERT

Use:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, col2 
  FROM othertable
```

You don't need the `VALUES` syntax if you are using a SELECT to populate the INSERT values.

Comment: Is it possible to combine Update & Insert so that if one fails, the other will be used without throwing an error (independently for each row). I think that would be a more complete solution to the question (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6527838/781695)

Answer (score 40):

OMG Ponies's answer works perfectly, but just in case you need something more complex, here is an example of a slightly more advanced update query:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET col1 = subquery.col2,
    col2 = subquery.col3 
FROM (
    SELECT t2.foo as col1, t3.bar as col2, t3.foobar as col3 
    FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.t2_id
    WHERE t2.created_at > '2016-01-01'
) AS subquery
WHERE table1.id = subquery.col1;
```

Comment: perfect. this works best wherein you need to pick a subset based on a condition involving the updated table itself.

Comment: @David Namenyi can you explain this query?

Answer (score 18):

```
UPDATE table1 SET (col1, col2) = (col2, col3) FROM othertable WHERE othertable.col1 = 123;
```