# PostgreSQL randomize foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have 2 tables in Postgres ( **inventory table** and **event table** ).
In the inventory table my primary key consist of 8 strings.
Example '03163161'.

Now I have to input them in the Event table randomly with the primary key that is on the inventory table.

In what way can I do it? I've tried googling it but no one seems to have a solution on it and I'm trying to experiment on how i can random input the PK of inventory table to the event table since the data is almost 3k.

Update#1

I've tried using the code below

```
INSERT INTO dashboard.event(terminal_id) VALUES (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.inventory)
```

but i get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO dashboard.event(terminal_id) VALUES (SELECT term...
                                                         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 50
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the keyword VALUES with a select in the insert.  See this question:

[Update or Insert (multiple rows and columns) from subquery in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736732/update-or-insert-multiple-rows-and-columns-from-subquery-in-postgresql)

```
INSERT INTO dashboard.event(terminal_id) 
SELECT terminal_id 
FROM dashboard.inventory --should work
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the 'references' keyword.  For example:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html

```
create table inventory
(
 id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 ... other fields
);

create table events
(
 eid INTEGER REFERENCES inventory(id),
 ... other fields
);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. But i'm not trying to create a table. I'm trying to insert random foreign keys on the event table.

Comment: I was hoping to see the SQL definition or \d the tables.  It's not completely clear to me what you are trying to do.  Do you want to select all the PKs from inventory, and then randomly put them in events?

Comment: Yes that's what i'm planning to do or just input them all in the event table